# Fixed-Point Theorem Question

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I am reading solution to this problem and I have questions.

In the fix point function in the problem is:

$g(x) =  (3x^2 + 3)^\frac{1}{4}$ and where x $\in$ [1,2]

And g prime is in the image I linked to.

[image]

My question is why is $k = 6^{-.5}$

That is, where does it come from?

Comment: Is this from ncert?

Comment: the value k is correct.

Comment: I usually plug in a or b where x in [a, b].

Comment: Oh, well I don't know. I just found it online.

Comment: @lhf, u seriously just gonna edit it instead of answering? SMH.